# Allow listing on all folders matching name (images) using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to allow listing (`Options +Indexes`) but only on a specific folder name.
The problem is that I have random folders inside a template folder and I want to allow listing only to folders named `images` that are under.

Is that possible with `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

In your root .htaccess place this line to disable directory listing globally:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Create `images/.htaccess` file and place this line:

```
Options +Indexes
```

Comment: I have more than 100 folders under 'templates' and each one have it's own 'images' folder inside. I need a rule that will work on root .htacess

Comment: Rewrite rules **cannot enable/disable Options**.

Comment: @anubhava I'd disagree: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options `Context: server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess`

Comment: You didn't understand my comment. Read again what I wrote **Rewrite rules cannot enable/disable Options**. `Options` can be customized in `.htaccess` but not via rewrite rules.

Comment: OK, sorry, but what do rewrite rules have to do with the original question? @Ovidiu didn't mention he'd be using rewrite rules at all.

Comment: OP wrote that in comment to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the [`<DirectoryMatch>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directorymatch) directive?

It should allow you to define similar code:

```
<DirectoryMatch "/images/">
    Options +Indexes
</DirectoryMatch>
```